# Can't figure out this simple recursion with Python

Tags: python, recursion

Maybe it's not so simple, but I am trying to essentially find all the permutations of a list of letters.

`[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]` for simplicity as it can be longer than just 3 lists of 2 (ie 6 lists of 3 letters, etc.).

I want my program to find all 8 combinations for above example while maintaining order of the main list (is that permutation?).

```
ace
acf
ade
adf
bce
bcf
bde
bdf
```

Currently I think the solution below will iterate recursively through the combinations I want; however, I cannot figure out how to store them in order because when it reaches the base condition for the first row it will simply go to the next letter in the last index of the list.

I don't believe I was able to find something that would work for me in `itertools`

```
def find_comb(mylist):

    for curr_index in range(0,len(mylist)):

        for letter in mylist[curr_index]:           

            if (curr_index+1<=len(mylist)):
               next_letter=find_comb(mylist[curr_index+1:])

    return 1     #wrote 1 for now because I am stumped
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: For argument's sake since I struggled with this for a while, if I was to fix what I have already how would I keep track of each permutation/product?

Comment: what do you mean by 'keep track of each permutation/product' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

x = [['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f']]

for _ in product(*x):
    print _
```

Prints

```
('a', 'c', 'e')
('a', 'c', 'f')
('a', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'd', 'f')
('b', 'c', 'e')
('b', 'c', 'f')
('b', 'd', 'e')
('b', 'd', 'f')
```

Regarding your comment:

`product` takes a bunch of iterables and generates their product, however, in your case you were sending it a single iterable (that consisted of more iterables). So instead of passing in `l1, l2, l3` you were passing in`[l1, l2, l3]`.

To actually pass in the three iterables, we have to unpack the list using the asterisk, which will turn that single list into three arguments. For more on that, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: Oh wow. i saw that, but it kept giving me a reference error. I didn't know I had to write it like that. I just simply wrote:

`x=itertools.product(mylist)`
`print(x)`

what does the asterisk mean and why did I have to iterate to print it correctly?